# How can this ReaderWriterLockSlim be blocked?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, locking

I've put together a thread-safe ObservableCollection to be used in WPF but am running into very occasionnal lock problems.

The locking mechanism is a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. To lighten the code in the collection itself, I've implemented an IDisposable helper:

```
    private class WriteLocker : IDisposable
    {
        ThreadSafeObservableCollection<T> _Target;
        bool _HasLock = false;


        public WriteLocker(ThreadSafeObservableCollection<T> target)
        {
            _Target = target;
            try { }
            finally
            {
                _Target._Sync.EnterWriteLock();
                _HasLock = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_HasLock)
            {
                try { }
                finally
                {
                    _Target._Sync.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

With an identical ReadLocker.

I can then use this in the collection this way:

```
    new public void Add(T item)
    {
        using (WriteLock())
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

And my notifications don't bother dispatchers because of:

```
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_Paused) return;

        NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler eventHandler = CollectionChanged;
        if (eventHandler == null)
            return;

        Delegate[] delegates = eventHandler.GetInvocationList();
        foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in delegates)
        {
            DispatcherObject dispatcherObject = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;
            if (dispatcherObject != null && dispatcherObject.CheckAccess() == false)
            {
                dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, e);
            }
            else
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now sometimes I end up locking up at `_Target._Sync.EnterWriteLock()`. In debugger, I can observe the ReaderWriterLockSlim's state:
[It has a writeLockOwnerId, but writeLockHeld is false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqqps.png)

My question is... how can this happen? I was under the impression that there was nothing I could do that wouldn't unlock my lock going out of a using(){} block. I'm also curious what situation could corrupt a lock this way - or is this a normal situation?

Edit:

Code for WriteLock() is simply:

```
    protected IDisposable WriteLock()
    {
        return new WriteLocker(this);
    }
```

And here's the complete code, for that matter: [ThreadSafeObservableCollection.cs](https://gist.github.com/obiben/180281e09eba2b53fdbfc73c27683f9d)

Comment: Can you show us the code for `WriteLock` and `ThreadSafeObservableCollection`?

Comment: Have you set _HasLock to false when Dispose? Could you a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: Probably not the cause of your issue here, but you should use the basic dispose pattern when using IDisposable - see here for details: [basic dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern#basic_pattern)

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is after all. Deadlock happens?

Comment: @mjwills Posted the whole class' code

Comment: @gabba I've posted the complete code, but using this class extensively, the lock happens about once every two days over basically billions of operations. I haven't found a way to systematically reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you by any chance forcibly aborting threads (e.g. via `Thread.Abort´) that may be using your collection?  According to **Joe Duffy**'s [blog](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/02/07/introducing-the-new-readerwriterlockslim-in-orcas/), this is a known cause for corrupt locking state

Comment: Your class looks very solid to me, I can't spot any obvious cause for deadlocking from the code. I am curious about the empty `try` blocks in your `ReadLocker`and `WriteLocker` constructors (with your locking logic inside the `finally` block). Is there a reason for this construct?

Comment: As an experiment, have you tried replacing the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` with the older `ReaderWriterLock` version?  According to the blog I posted, it appears to be very slow, but perhaps it is more robust than the slim version.

Comment: Here is an interesting [article](http://chabster.blogspot.mx/2013/07/a-story-of-orphaned-readerwriterlockslim.html) analyzing a corrupted `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and again, blaming aborted threads.  I must say it has been a very interesting question for me. I wasn't aware of any potential pitfalls of using `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, a class I tend to frequently use.  Cheers!

Comment: LOL, I found out in the last article I referenced the reason of your strange-looking try-finally blocks, you are running that code in a 'protected' region, again a very didactic question for me. I didn't know this was the proper pattern for acquiring the lock!

Comment: Another interesting blog [entry](http://chabster.blogspot.mx/2013/12/readerwriterlockslim-fails-on-dual.html), where it seems that there was a bug (later corrected) inside the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` logic.

Comment: @BlueStrat Glad to be of entertainment/didactic value. Indeed the empty try's are there only to run my acquiry in protected areas. 

Your last link may be of value, I will look into it; maybe have to change locks. Some commenter says he still experiences the issue even on 4.5.2... Good google-fu on your part!